# Is there a rerender event for Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, minimongo

Is there a rerender event or event fired when when minimongo db changes in Meteor.js?

I am making a messenger with meteor js and i need to scroll down when i get a new message and thisbshould be done when new message(html) is inserted by meteor.

Comment: This is a problematic UX pattern on its own (I would prefer a small notification that invites me to click to see new messages). If you insist on scrolling on new messages, then perhaps keeping a scroll position as a state variable and updating it upon a new message will be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare anything in the template onRendered function
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered

If your messages are single templates, then it will be fired on every render.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any details about your implementation, since you haven't supplied any code examples, so I can only suggest that maybe meteor-collection-hooks is what you are looking for. The guide says that they can be used on the client, server and both.

If by *minimongo db* you mean that you are using a client side only collection, then you should be aware that it won't persist on page reloads.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer